# jQuery autocomplete working locally but not working while running via server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tomcat

I am trying to implement autocomplete feature with JQuery UI methods. The entire code works fine when running on local host. But when I uploaded this onto a remote server, and then access the file, it doesn't work.
I could not find any error log too...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#calendar_Frm" ).datepicker();
    $("#calendar_To" ).datepicker();

    var availableTutorials=new Array();
    <% String[] codes=(String[])request.getAttribute("fellowInfoArray");
    if(codes!=null){
        for(int i=0; i<codes.length; i++){ %>
            var code='<%= codes[i] %>';          
            availableTutorials[<%= i %>]=code; 
        <%}
    }%>
     $( "#auto_complete" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTutorials
     });   }); </script>
```

Comment: Only valid answer to "Doesn't work" is "You did something wrong". That doesn't look like valid ECMAScript and did you try pressing F12 to open the developer tools in the browser to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Yeah, your are right. If really there is something wrong, then it should not work in locally too. Right? @HMR2

Comment: So post your error log also.

Comment: I am not able find any errors while hitting the url.